# Does ioremap_wc() create a structure of pages and many of PTEs?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, paging

As known that MMIO space is mapped (for example via /dev/mem, by calling remap_pfn_range()) as a single PTE so there is no struct page.

Does the the same thing when using `ioremap_wc()`, or does `ioremap_wc()` create a structure of pages and many of PTEs?

OS: Linux x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confusingly expressed but I think I can answer.

First, to be clear, an mmap of /dev/mem (using remap_pfn_range) does *not* guarantee to use only a single PTE. If the area to be mapped fits within a single page, it would only use one; otherwise, it uses as many as are needed. (A PTE is a page-table-entry; hence it maps exactly one physical page. The page size (or sizes) is of course architecture-dependent.)

A "struct page" is used to manage real memory -- that is: system RAM / non-MMIO space. (Both RAM and MMIO space are physical pages in the sense that they occupy physical address space and have addresses, but struct page is used only for general purpose memory into which programs and arbitrary data can be placed.)

It is correct that ioremap_wc and all the other ioremap variants are much like mmap'ing MMIO space via /dev/mem, except that they're exclusively for kernel use. At the lowest level, they end up using the same code to create PTEs (except those PTEs reference kernel virtual address space instead of user virtual address space). The ioremap call allocates a "vm_struct" to track the virtual to physical mapping, then sets up the PTEs to actually map virtual address to physical.

The primary difference then is in how they are tracked/managed. Kernel code is expected to cleanly deallocate / release its own VM areas and PTEs. OTOH, a user process is not trusted to do this. Hence, the mmap of /dev/mem sets up VM structures that are associated to the process so that if the process exits, the kernel can find and release any mappings and so forth itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please, can you clarify? **1.** "The ioremap call allocates a "vm_struct" to track the virtual to physical mapping, then sets up the PTEs to actually map virtual address to physical." - do you mean that `ioremap_wc()` call to `vm_insert_page()`? **2.** `mmap of /dev/mem` does not call to `vm_insert_page()`? **3.** In both cases (1.`ioremap_wc(); mmap();` and 2.`mmap of /dev/mem`) can I easily gain access to the structure of the pages by pointer in user-space, which I get by `mmap()`?

Comment: You can't gain access to ioremap'd area from user mode. It's for kernel use only; it maps pages into kernel virtual address space and you won't be able to access that space or any info about it from user mode. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Finally I want to know why should I "Using `vm_insert_page` for every page instead works" to use my Ethernet NIC buffer from GPU? That said bottom on page 27 - the last paragraph: http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~koromil/files/mscthesis.pdf

Comment: I don't have time to read the whole thing but at a glance it looks like the author of that thesis is implementing a hack to adapt an existing model to a piece of software he can't change ("the driver comes as a binary blob with no source code available"). It looks like he's replacing what would ordinarily be remap_pfn_range (would work fine on MMIO space) with the vm_insert_page operation so that he can map non-MMIO pages instead.

Comment: Thanks. He want to map NIC PCIe-BAR -> CPU user-space -> GPU-UVA(Unified Virtual Addressing). But PCIe-BAR is MMIO, isn't it? And how using `vm_insert_page()` instead of `remap_pfn_range()` can help to map non-MMIO?